# Weather Forecast Doesn't Work

Tags: big-sur, widgets

The system is Big Sur (11.0.1) and weather forecast widget doesn't work time to time. When it is out of order it says something like "weather forecast is unsuccesful". Here is a screenshot.

[image]

How can I fix it and the widget starts to work as in Catalina?

Comment: What makes you think this isn’t a network timeout?

Comment: @bmike I don't know, is it?

Comment: Could be a network issue, could also suffer from Big Sur being brand new and not all of the bugs being worked out..

Comment: Unrelated to the question: you can create screenshots of only a part of the screen with Cmd-Shift-4.

Comment: As other have eluded to, the widget not responding can be due to any number of issues ranging from the new OS to a network connection issue from your Mac all the way to the data center at the other end to the server hosting the weather data having issues.  Try narrowing this down a bit by trying a different OS or computer.  You can also try a different network by taking your computer (if it's a laptop) to a different network like a coffee shop.

Comment: Never found a weather app that can reliably predict weather anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Since the failure is time to time, it’s likely you do not have a configuration issue. If it never worked, then a call to Apple support would likely get to the bottom of a persistent failure.

Do you have any support from your network provider?

I often tether to a smart phone when troubleshooting an internet connection if I can’t move my Mac easily.

Comment: Network provider sounds reluctant to do anything. They just told me to contact Apple Support. I will try to use different connections to check whether the problem is persistent.